# how to delegate mousedown and mouseup on a dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`rollmark` is created dynamically so I need to delegate events to `document`

Trying to to perform one action while `rollmark` is pressed, and another one when the mouse is released but I'm getting a syntax error.

pls help.

```js
$(document).on({'mousedown', '.rollmark' function(e){  
    console.log('down');
},
mouseup: function(){
    console.log('up');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='rollmark'>CLICK</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call `.on` separately for each handler if you want event delegation:

```js
$(document)
  .on('mousedown', '.rollmark', function(e) {
    console.log('down');
  })
  .on('mouseup', '.rollmark', function() {
    console.log('up');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='rollmark'>CLICK</div>
```

Comment: You'd need `.rollmark` in `mouseup` too, otherwise it'd fire on _any_ element's mouseup event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '.rollmark', function(e) {  
  console.log('down');
}).on('mouseup', '.rollmark', function(e) {  
  console.log('up');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='rollmark'>CLICK</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting comma after '.rollmark'?